# How to get rid of padding to the left of suffixIcon? Because of the padding cursor is not centered correctly

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is the code:

```
TextField(
                        controller: _textEditingController,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                width: 4.0,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                          focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            borderSide: new BorderSide(
                              style: BorderStyle.solid,
                              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                              width: 4.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: _getFillColorBasedOnInput(context),
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/images/checkmark_yellow.svg',
                                color: _textEditingController.text.isEmpty ? Colors.black12 : null,
                                width: 32.0,
                                height: 32.0,
                              )),
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        ))
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone suggest some solutions to center cursor against the beginning of an input field and a checkmark icon (see red dotted line). I have tried a lot of ideas but none of them led to the desired result. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 things that you can do here:

1) Change the code of the suffix icon in the flutter files by removing the extra `padding`.

2) This is a workaround, you can use `Stack` Widget to keep your icon above the `Textfield`. This way you'll have the cursor centred.
Although, it will look unpleasant if your typed text is too long (i.e. Your  typed input below icon). In that case you might limit your lnput.

Comment: I don't understand the first option quite well. `suffixIcon` is implemented in `input_decorator.dart` Flutter file. It is over 3k lines of code. Do you mean to copy this file and modify? The second option worked for me. Added padding to the end of Textfield, got rid of `suffixIcon` usage, added an icon using the Stack, positioned it and it looks great now.

Comment: You can change the code directly in flutter files as well. Ofcourse copy pasting and changing code doesn't seem right here (I have edited my answer). Make sure to keep a note that you have changed the flutter code. After finishing your app, i would recommend you to change it back.